# Scheduling over different AWS Components - Glue and EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-glue

I was wondering how I would tackle the following on AWS? - or whether it was not possible?

- Transient EMR Cluster for some bulk Spark processing
- When that cluster terminates, then and only then use a Glue Job to do some limited processing

I am not convinced AWS Glue Triggers will help over environments.

Or could one say, well just keep on in the EMR Cluster, it's not a good use case? Glue can write to SAP Hana with appropriate Connector and Redshift Spectrum is common use case to load Redshift via Glue job with Redshift Spectrum.

Comment: You can use "Run a job" service integration using AWS Step Functions. Step functions supports both EMR and Glue integration.

Comment: @dossani. i thought that glue was totally independant as serverless and emr is ec2. can u point to docs on this pls? sounds like an answer.

Comment: @dossani. indeed i found it. suggest you post answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Run a job" service integration using AWS Step Functions. Step functions supports both EMR and Glue integration.
Please refer to the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-supported-services.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Having spoken to Amazon on this aspect, they indicate that Airflow via MWAA is the preferred option now.